# How can I keep cards in a carousel slide from wrapping to two lines?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 to create a website and I am using it to create a carousel as well. I am trying to  get all the items in the carousel to be aligned vertically. However I am having trouble doing that. Can you please help me?

### This is what it currently looks like [image]

### This what I want it to look like [image]

```css
.crd {
  background: hsl(233, 47%, 96%);
  transition: all;
}

.crd:hover {
  background: hsl(216, 90%, 44%);
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card img {
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  background: hsl(233, 47%, 96%);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="description" content="..." />

  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" /> -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet" title="Default" disabled href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d">
  <link rel="stylesheet" data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet" title="Web Awesome" href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="/_bridgetown/static/js/main.96ffffaea92690057bfb.js" defer></script> -->
</head>

<body>
  <!-- OUR CLIENTS SECTION START -->
  <section class="bg-dark text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-white py-5">
        <h2 class="display-6"></h2>
        <div class="col-12">
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#carouseldemo1" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#carouseldemo1" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" id="carouseldemo1">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card text-center p-4 mb-2">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-camera-cctv fa-3x"></i>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4>CCTV Services</h4>
                        <p class="p-2">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem. Quisquam
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card text-center p-4 mb-2">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-camera-cctv fa-3x"></i>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4>CCTV Services</h4>
                        <p class="p-2">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem. Quisquam
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card text-center p-4 mb-2">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-camera-cctv fa-3x"></i>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4>CCTV Services</h4>
                        <p class="p-2">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem. Quisquam
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card text-center p-4 mb-2">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-camera-cctv fa-3x"></i>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4>CCTV Services</h4>
                        <p class="p-2">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem. Quisquam
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card text-center p-4 mb-2">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-camera-cctv fa-3x"></i>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4>CCTV Services</h4>
                        <p class="p-2">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem. Quisquam
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card text-center p-4 mb-2">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-camera-cctv fa-3x"></i>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4>CCTV Services</h4>
                        <p class="p-2">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem. Quisquam
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card text-center p-4 mb-2">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-camera-cctv fa-3x"></i>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4>CCTV Services</h4>
                        <p class="p-2">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem. Quisquam
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- OUR CLIENTS SECTION CLOSE -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `col-4` (of 12, or 1/3 width) on your cards in that panel. The [grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/#grid-options) lay it out fairly clearly. You're assigning the number of portions of a 12-portion grid you want your column to use. Obviously 4/12 is 1/3, so your cards in that carousel slide are too wide. You want four cards to each take 1/4 instead (3/12).

Use `col-3` (of 12, or 1/4 width), or just use `col`.

```css
.crd {
  background: hsl(233, 47%, 96%);
  transition: all;
}

.crd:hover {
  background: hsl(216, 90%, 44%);
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card img {
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  background: hsl(233, 47%, 96%);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="description" content="..." />

  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" /> -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet" title="Default" disabled href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d">
  <link rel="stylesheet" data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet" title="Web Awesome" href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="/_bridgetown/static/js/main.96ffffaea92690057bfb.js" defer></script> -->
</head>

<body>
  <!-- OUR CLIENTS SECTION START -->
  <section class="bg-dark text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-white py-5">
        <h2 class="display-6"></h2>
        
        <div class="col-12 mb-2">
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#carouseldemo1" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#carouseldemo1" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" id="carouseldemo1">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card text-center p-4 mb-2">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-camera-cctv fa-3x"></i>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4>CCTV Services</h4>
                        <p class="p-2">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem. Quisquam
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card text-center p-4 mb-2">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-camera-cctv fa-3x"></i>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4>CCTV Services</h4>
                        <p class="p-2">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem. Quisquam
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card text-center p-4 mb-2">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-camera-cctv fa-3x"></i>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4>CCTV Services</h4>
                        <p class="p-2">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem. Quisquam
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="card text-center p-4 mb-2">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-camera-cctv fa-3x"></i>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4>CCTV Services</h4>
                        <p class="p-2">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem. Quisquam
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="card text-center p-4 mb-2">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-camera-cctv fa-3x"></i>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4>CCTV Services</h4>
                        <p class="p-2">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem. Quisquam
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="card text-center p-4 mb-2">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-camera-cctv fa-3x"></i>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4>CCTV Services</h4>
                        <p class="p-2">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem. Quisquam
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="card text-center p-4 mb-2">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-camera-cctv fa-3x"></i>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4>CCTV Services</h4>
                        <p class="p-2">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem. Quisquam
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- OUR CLIENTS SECTION CLOSE -->
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I really appreciate it. I'm new to Bootstrap and I really don't under between col-3 and col-4. I really don't understand columns that much.

Comment: @Amodh, that is incorrect. The grid docs I linked above explain it quite clearly.